# How to enable "AutoLayout" of iOS 6 programmatically?

Tags: ios5, ios6

How can I enable "AutoLayout" programmatically. Actually I have to create an app which should run on iOS6 and iOS5 but we can enable "AutoLayout" in the XIB in iOS 6 only and it will not work on the iOS 5 so I am checking the iOS version and using if else condition for the appropriate task according to the iOS. So if app would be running on iOS 6, I will enable the AutoLayout otherwise I will write the code for AutoResizing. Please let me know if I am unclear at any point.

Comment: I think you just need to use [NSLayoutConstraint](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/NSLayoutConstraint/NSLayoutConstraint.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSLayoutConstraint) to for using AutoLayout

Comment: @Bala Yes Bala, that I understood but my query is that if I use AutoLayout, will app work on iOS 5 because NSLayoutConstraint is introduced in iOS 6 only and it won't work with iOS 5 and I need to create app which can run on both iOS.

Comment: you can borrow ideas from https://github.com/RolandasRazma/RRAutoLayout

Answer (score 1):

If you want autolayout on iOS6 devices but not iOS5 (unuspported) but still want to use nib's, you have to keep separate nibs. One for iOS5 and one for iOS6.

When loading your nib, check if autolayout is supported by checking if the NSLayoutConstraint class exists:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"NSLayoutConstraint"))
    //Load iOS6 nib with autlayout.
else
    //Load iOS5 nib sans autolayout.
```